# Apache Ignite : Continuous SQLFieldQuery

Tags: java, ignite

I am looking to expose Apache Ignite Cache and client application can access the same. I can see Continuous query support in Apache Ignite version 1.9 -
https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheContinuousAsyncQueryExample.java

However I am not able to find any example how to implement Continuous SQLFieldQuery.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Run Spring example!!");
        Ignition.setClientMode(true);
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setIncludeEventTypes( EVTS_CACHE);
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder discoveryMulticastIpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

        set.add("serverhost:47500..47509");
        discoveryMulticastIpFinder.setAddresses(set);

        TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        discoverySpi.setIpFinder(discoveryMulticastIpFinder);

        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi);

        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        cfg.setIncludeEventTypes(EVTS_CACHE);
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

        CacheConfiguration<String, BinaryObject> cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>(CACHE_NAME);


        IgniteCache<String, BinaryObject> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration).withKeepBinary();


        QueryCursor<List<?>> query = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select Field1 from table1 where Field1='TEST'"));
            List<List<?>> all = query.getAll();
            for (List<?> l : all) {
                System.out.println(l);
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuous queries are only predicate based, SQL is not supported here. You can provide a remote filter that will be called for every update on server side. All updates that satisfy the filter, will be batched and sent to the subscriber, where local listener is invoked.

Refer to this page for details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries